# Unknown behaviour of OR operator in C++

Tags: c++, logic

I have this code running by chance and when i put anything as the answer it is showing me correct. I know we have to put ans before YES and yay, but this code was compiled too, as i mentioned if i put any word as the input the output is correct:

```
string ans;
cin >> ans;

if(ans == "yes" || "YES" || "yay") {
    cout << "Correct";
}else {
    cout << "Incorrect";
}
```

Comment: Boolean operators don't work like that. All they do is take two bool values (true or false) and return a bool value. That's the only thing they do.

Comment: Anything nonzero is true.  `"YES"` is always true.  `"yay"` is always true.  You are forgetting to compare those against something.

Comment: @FeiXiang i didn't get it.

Comment: @DrewDormann why is it always true?

Comment: Forget everything you know about the word "OR" in English. Like I said, the only thing `||` does is return true if at least one of its inputs is true.

Comment: @FeiXiang i know what is a OR in logic. But if i input ANYTHING even if i put NO, i will get Correct as an output. I know the working form is to write ans=="yes" || ans=="YES" || ans=="yay", but why the form in the question is working like that.

Comment: You are trying to make three comparisons, but you have only written one.

Comment: there should be a duped of this somewhere.

Comment: When you give `"YES"` to the `||` operator which takes a boolean value, it get's converted to a boolean value. When you convert something to a boolean, you get false if it is 0, and true for anything else.

Comment: @codekaizer there will be, but for naught. This isn't the sort of thing you can easily Google.

Comment: I just asked a question (which is stackoverflow is made for), but you are giving negative rates. Nice.

Comment: `if(ans == "yes" || "YES" || "yay")` is equivalent to `if(ans == "yes" || true || true )`.  That is always true.  Maybe or true or true is never false.

Comment: @Shahryar downvotes are most likely because this question is asked every other day and is easily explained by working through statement and taking [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) into account. I don't downvote over this one because, like I said, above, it's really hard to websearch.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but others probably did because they considered this to be too basic, and can be solved by carefully reading a textbook or asking your professor.

Comment: I'm not saying that you shouldn't try stuff that you haven't been taught, but just don't assume that they will work and get confused when they don't.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks. A question may seem to be basic. But look at the answers some people provided below. I have questions with 10000 views... I just didn't know this answer.

Comment: Someone should make a canonical "Why does my comparison to multiple values always return true" question.

Comment: @AShelly I thought of doing that, but I was afraid it would be downvoted as too basic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok here's the precedence (L->R) and associativity of logic wise operators:

`(((ans == "yes") || "YES") || "yay")`

Since C/C++ has **no chaining** unlike Python.

1st: `ans == "yes"` -> `str` to `str` comparison

2nd: `bool result of 1st || "YES"` ->  `bool` and `str` comparison = always `true` for `"YES"` is not null

3rd: `true || "YES"` = always `true`

Thus, the condition will always be `true` for `"YES"` and `"yay"` are not null.

Comment: Thanks i understand it now.

Comment: "always true for "YES" is not empty" isn't quite correct. It's always true as "YES" is a non-null pointer. `if ("")` would also be true

Comment: @AlanBirtles, modified. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have the precedence wrong.

`if (var == A || B || C)` means "if (var is equal to A) OR (B is not zero) OR (C is not zero)"

You want to do `if (var == A || var == B || var == C)`.  That means "if (var is equal to A) OR (var is equal to B) or (var is equal to C)"

Comment: i know what is a OR in logic. But if i input ANYTHING even if i put NO, i will get Correct as an output. I know the working form is to write ans=="yes" || ans=="YES" || ans=="yay", but why the form in the question is working like that.

Comment: Because "YES" is a non-zero value, so inside the if statement, it is always true.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare ans with each value. Every comparison with value is not "0" or "fail" value is assumed as "true". So if you input the if a condition like if("yes") it always returns a true.

```
int main()
{
    std::string ans;
    std::cin >> ans;

    if("yes" == ans || "YES" == ans || "yay" == ans)
    {
        std::cout << "Correct\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Incorrect";
    }
}
```